# how to add string if word ended with specific string

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed, perl

we want to update the following file , in case MACHINE_NAME ended with **".localdomain"** then need to  add the string linux in the beginning of the word

each MACHINE_NAME comes with single brackets '......'

example of file before changing

```
['server_primary01.localdomain', 'server_primary02.localdomain', 'server_primary03.localdomain']
EDIT_HOSTS.append( {'HOST' : 'Client0{0}.localdomain'.format(count+1)} )
EDIT_HOSTS.append( {'HOST' : 'Client{0}.localdomain'.format(count+1)} )
EDIT_HOSTS.append( {'HOST' : 'Client0{0}.localdomain'.format(count+1)} )
EDIT_HOSTS.append( {'HOST' : 'Client{0}.localdomain'.format(count+1)} )
```

example after changing

```
        ['linuxserver_primary01.localdomain', 'linuxserver_primary02.localdomain', 'linuxserver_primary03.localdomain']
        EDIT_HOSTS.append( {'HOST' : 'linuxClient0{0}.localdomain'.format(count+1)} )
        EDIT_HOSTS.append( {'HOST' : 'linuxClient{0}.localdomain'.format(count+1)} )
        EDIT_HOSTS.append( {'HOST' : 'linuxClient0{0}.localdomain'.format(count+1)} )
        EDIT_HOSTS.append( {'HOST' : 'linuxClient{0}.localdomain'.format(count+1)} )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`sed`** solution:

```
sed -E "s/[^[:space:]']+\.localdomain/linux&/g" file
```

Sample output:

```
['linuxserver_primary01.localdomain', 'linuxserver_primary02.localdomain', 'linuxserver_primary03.localdomain']
EDIT_HOSTS.append( {'HOST' : 'linuxClient0{0}.localdomain'.format(count+1)} )
EDIT_HOSTS.append( {'HOST' : 'linuxClient{0}.localdomain'.format(count+1)} )
EDIT_HOSTS.append( {'HOST' : 'linuxClient0{0}.localdomain'.format(count+1)} )
EDIT_HOSTS.append( {'HOST' : 'linuxClient{0}.localdomain'.format(count+1)} )
```